# pops an error when i am updating the form and include :url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new to ruby on rails and got an error while following http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html tutorial.the error come at when i am updating the form like this    "<%= form_for :post, URL :posts_path do |f| %>"..When i move my cursor to that error it says Unexpected tSYMBEG..i just followed the instructions...The error occur on 2nd line .any help will be appreciable

```
<h1>New Post</h1>
<%= form_for :post, url :posts_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<%= form_for @post do |f| %>` will do. Otherwise, try this: `<%= form_for :post, url: :posts_path do |f| %>`

Comment: Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <h1>New Post</h1>
2: <%= form_for :post, url :posts_path do |f| %>
3:   <p>
4:     <%= f.label :title %><br />
5:     <%= f.text_field :title %>

Comment: The error message is not the one one. Here's how I can help you better: a) give me the code of the view which is throwing up the error. b) the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. It causes the issue.

replace

```
url :posts_path
```

with

```
url: posts_path
```

You can also use.

```
<%= form_for :post, :url => posts_path do |f| %>
```

or

```
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
```

All are same..